# how to use draftjs editor in function based components in react?

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, rich-text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I want to work with rich text editor but I cannot find any informative documentation to use in `react function base components`.I used the `wysiwyg` editor by `draftjs` the text editor is shown as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOPXm.png)

the code of the react file is

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import cityContext from "../context/cities/CityContext"
export default function CreatePost(props) {
    // const [editorState,setState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const cities = useContext(cityContext);
    let editorState = useState("");
    const onEditorStateChange = () => {
        // alert("here");
        console.log(editorState);
    }
    return (
        <div>

            <Modal className="text-center"
                {...props}
                size="lg"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Body >
                    <input type="text" className="form-control my-2 p-3" placeholder='Enter title of the text'></input>
                    <input type="file" className="form-control my-2 p-3" placeholder='Enter title of the text'></input>
                    <select name="" id="" className="form-control  cityField p-3 my-2" placeholder='select city'>
                        <option className='cityField' value="">--select city for the article--</option>
                        {cities.map(cityObj => <option key={cityObj.city} value="" className='cityField' >
                            {cityObj.city}</option>)}
                    </select>

                    <Editor className="editor"
                        onChange={onEditorStateChange}
                    />

                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button className="btn btn-danger form-control" onClick={props.onHide}>cancel</Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-success form-control" onClick={props.onHide}>submit</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I cannot find any solution that How I can handle the input data and how to store the input data in any variable to store the data in database.

Answer (score 0):

`react-draft-wysiwyg` is using `draft-js` as core of the package and you can use this link to achieve what you want:
https://draftjs.org/docs/quickstart-api-basics#controlling-rich-text

Keep in mind that you have to create the initial state of editorState with `EditorState.createEmpty()`

EditorState should be available to import from `react-draft-wysiwyg`.